# Why cant windows7 pc on domain share files off domain without first rdp?

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-sharing

We have a shared folder that cannot be accessed until after you remote desktop in.

Our requirement is two laptops (a&b) are going to work out of the office and need to share files via windows shared folder. On laptop A we made a local user through computer management and granted administrator access. We share a folder on this computer and grant access to the local user. We unplug both laptops from our internal network restart them and connect both together via wi-fi.

Computer b tries browsing to \a\share - it sits there for ages and nothing happens. Computer b remote desktops to computer A - logs in using the local user account ie. a\localuse then logs out. Computer b tries again browsing to \a\share - logs in as a\localuser and works fine.

Not sure what we have done wrong here or why remote first desktop fixes it. Any ideas apreaciated?

These laptops have windows 7 pro with latest patches.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the firewall completely on both computers while on wifi?

Comment: Is this a one time thing, or is the process needed every time you try to share files?